# Constructor props state vs simply state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I started learning React when we could simply use state and create object instead of using  `constructor(props){ super(props)`

Now, I see many libraries where they are still using

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
```

So my first question is if there is an advantage of using `constructor (props) super(props)` and then setting up state? instead of just creating state object?

Second question, I wanted to implement [react-native-slowlog](https://github.com/jondot/react-native-slowlog) in the native app I am making.

Throughout the code I have created the `state object` directly instead of using constructor.

The documentation for the **react-native-slowlog** shows this way to use it

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    slowlog(this, /.*/)

    this.state = this.getDataSource(props)
    this.shouldComponentUpdate = shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this)
  }
...
}
```

Where they call  `slowlog(this, /.*/)` inside the constructor, so my question is can I avoid using constructor here? or is it okay if I create a constructor where I do    `slowlog(this, /.*/)` and then create state object outside the constructor?

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super() 
    slowlog(this, /.*/)
  } 


  state = {
    searchCoin: false
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to skip explicit `constructor` if `state` is all you need to define, because this can be done with [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields):

```
class Master extends Component {
  state = { searchCoin: false };
  ...
```

Which is syntactic sugar for ES6:

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchCoin: false };
  } 
  ...
```

This is a matter of taste whether `state` is defined as class field or as a part of `constructor` body if there's a need for `constructor`; class field takes less characters to type because it doesn't contain `this.`

Also notice that

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super() 
    slowlog(this, /.*/)
  } 

  state = { searchCoin: false }
  ...
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
class Master extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super() 
    this.state = { searchCoin: false };
    slowlog(this, /.*/)
  } 
  ...
```

Class fields go after `super` and before other constructor statements. This may not work as intended if `slowlog` is expected to run first.

Comment: Since I haven't using constructor a lot, is it a good idea to call a redux action     `this.props.CurrencyRate()` in constructor instead of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount`

Comment: This depends on how CurrencyRate works. componentWillMount is deprecated in favour of constructor. If it's async and works the same way in componentDidMount as it would in constructor then componentDidMount is the right place.

Comment: @KuchBhi don’t use constructor for Api calls. The main intention of providing constructor in React is to do Pre-initialling state and doing function/object bindings and accessing parent props when you want to pre-initialise the state with props from parent. You are recommended to do Api calls in componentDidMount and do setState accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

- Why uses `constructor (props){}` and `super(props)`?

The only reason is when you want to access `this` inside of the constructor [React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/52752446760dee0bc7232b4146f5a309ac57f065/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L23)

if you pass:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)

         console.log(this.props)
         // goood
     }
 }
```

if you are not passing but call super

```
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super()

         console.log(this.props)
         // -> undefined

         // Props parameter is still available
         console.log(props)
         // good
     }

     render() {
         // No difference outside constructor
         console.log(this.props)
         // good
     }
 }
```

if you dont call

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
           console.log(this)
         // undefined
     }
 }
```

So in summary that is not always needed.

- set state in constructor vs outside

That is just syntax sugar, therefore no difference.

constructor only get calls once per mount, so you want to do stuffs that you don't want to do on every render.

Comment: I was under impression that OP wasn't interested in `super()` vs `super(props)`, this was just pasted code, but that's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the constructor if you are initializing state or binding functions.

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t
>   need to implement a constructor for your React component. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

So for what the library you linked to does, you do need to call it in the constructor.  It both initializes the state and binds to the shouldComponentUpdate function.

However, if you aren't binding to anything you could always initialize the state directly on the property like this...

Typescript

```
class Master extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public readonly state = { someKey: "Initial Value" };
}
```

Javascript

```
class Master extends React.Component {
  state = { someKey: "Initial Value" };
}
```

Also I am not sure what the `this.getDataSource(props)` function does, and if that is just the example provided by slowlog.  But initializing the state on the class property AND from the constructor won't wont.  So you can do it like your example showed OR you could call that function from the componentDidMount function.

```
class Master extends React.Component {
  // initialize your state
  state = { someKey: "Initial Value" };

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    slowlog(this /*, */);

    this.shouldComponentUpdate = shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const nextState = this.getDataSource(this.props);
    this.setState(nextState);
  }
}
```

On thing to note is that if `getDataSource` returns a promise, that should be called when the component mounts, rather than from the constructor.

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: @estus that is okay, the lifecycle remains the same regardless of TS, Flow or JS.  You can just remove the typing for the Class and State